# Echoing a single quoted array's value inside another single quoted array value

Tags: php

I am trying to echo the value of 'test', inside the output of 'test2' when the last one is shown in my screen, but with no luck.
Every test I did, returned no BASICTEST in the text, so I am sure that I am missing something critical.

Any help would be appreciated.
Here is my array's code:

```
'test' => 'BASICTEST',
'test2' => "<div id=\"secondary\">secondary test made after 'test'</div>"
```

Comment: `$array['test2'] = '<div id="secondary">'. $array['test'] .'</div>'`

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: You cannot address the contents of the array until the array is fully created. That does not happen until the closing `);` or `];` has been reached

Answer (score 0):

If I get your issue, you want to insert **BASICTEST** inside the `<div>`.

```
<?php   
function str_insert($str, $search, $insert) {
    $index = strpos($str, $search);
    if($index === false) {
        return $str;
    }
    return substr_replace($str, $search.$insert, $index, strlen($search));
}

$arr = array();
$arr = ["test" => "BASICTEST", "test2" => "<div id='secondary'>secondary test made after ''</div>"];
$str = $arr['test2'];
$add = $arr['test'];

$res = str_insert($str, "<div id='secondary'>secondary test made after '", $add);
$new_arr = array();
$new_arr = ["test" => "$add", "test2" => "$res"];
var_dump($new_arr);
```

You can test it here : 
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a051adbfe93d5fa968a44dbbe9f305e1a3a5e9e0

Comment: i would prefer not to change the structure of the code. Im wondering if there is another way to have it set as a variable and then output again via double quotes or related.

Comment: What do you mean by the structure of the code ? You didn't post any code

Comment: I mean that my array includes 'test' and 'test2'. Inside the value of 'test' I would like to also output the value of 'test2'. Something like my second code's line - which obviously has syntax errors and instead of outputting the dynamic code, it outputs a single text.

Comment: The expected out put for test2 is <div id="secondary">secondary test made after BASICTEST</div> - I hope that this makes more clear my question and Im sorry if it wasnt much clearer from the start. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

```
$array = array(
    'test' => 'BASICTEST',
    'test2' => '<div id="secondary">secondary test made after '.$array["test"].'</div>';
);

echo $array['test2'];
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to that code? Why do you think that it solves the problem?

Comment: Please add some context to the _code snippet_ for the benifit of the future readers.